# React - Nested maps to retrieve json data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

So I'm a bit new to javascript and react in general, so I've been practicing. Right now I was trying to retrieve JSON data and use that to render multiple HTML blocks pretty much like a basic schedule. For example, initially, my JSON was formatted as so

```
{
  "saturday":[
  {
    "event": 1
  },
  {
    "event": 2
  }
 ]
}
```

and I used a function like the following to map for each part of the JSON array

```
initialize = events => {
  return events.map(this.createBlock)
}
```

Here createBlock is another function returning the following.

```
createBlock = events =>{
 return(
    <Scheduled
       event={events.event}   
    />
 );
```

this way when calling the initialize function in render It would create two event blocks but according to the individual data from createBlock in this case just the event number (Scheduled is just the file in which I format how the data from createBlock will be returned as with styling).

And I called all of this in my jsx with

```
{this.initialize(data.saturday)}
```

where data is the JSON asset imported in

But now I wanted to do the same but on nested JSON data. So it would look like this. So now instead of directly make multiple event blocks. It would make multiple time blocks each with multiple event blocks inside of them.

```
"saturday":{
  "time":{
    "9:00": [
      {
        "event": 1
      },
      {
        "event": 2
      }
    ],
    "10:00":[
      {
        "event": 1
      },
      {
        "event": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm just confused on how to approach this. I was thinking about maybe a nested map but wasn't sure if that was practical. Any advice/help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first level, you have an object and at the second level is the array and hence in order to use map, you need to make use of [`Object.entries(it returns an array of arrays as key value pairs)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) at the first level

```
initialize = day => {
  return Object.entries(day.time).map(this.createBlock)
}

createBlock = ([time, events]) =>{
 return (
     <div>
        <p>{time}</p>
       {events.map(this.createEvent)}
     </div>
 );

createEvent = event =>{
 return(
    <Scheduled
       event={event.event}   
    />
 );
```

```js
const data = {
  "saturday": {
    "time": {
      "9:00": [{
          "event": 1
        },
        {
          "event": 2
        }
      ],
      "10:00": [{
          "event": 1
        },
        {
          "event": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

const Scheduled = ({
  event
}) => {
  return <div > {
    event
  } < /div>
}

class App extends React.Component {

  initialize = day => {
    return <div > {
      Object.entries(day.time).map(this.createBlock)
    } < /div>
  }

  createBlock = ([time, events]) => {
    return ( <
        div key = {
          time
        } >
        <
        p > {
          time
        } < /p> {
        events.map(this.createEvent)
      } <
      /div>
  );
}

createEvent = event => {
  return ( <
    Scheduled key = {
      event.event
    }
    event = {
      event.event
    }
    />
  )
}


render() {
  return ( <
    div > {
      this.initialize(data.saturday)
    } <
    /div>
  )
}
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help. This makes a lot more sense then the method I was trying.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can go with nested map.

`initialize = timings => {
  return timings.map(this.createEvents)
}`

then

`createEvents = events => {
  return events.map(this.createBlock)
}`

finally

`{this.initialize(data.saturday)}`

Comment: You should have to use object.keys to get array of keys from the object and then map.